# Automatic exploit searches

Tags: penetration-test, exploit, exploit-kits, exploit-development

How to automatically search and download exploits which matches for example with kernel release ?

Is there for example a public REST web service which provide data in XML or JSON format to a client program ?

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT :**

Solution 1 : @Lucas_Kauffman

Parse HTML search results of db-exploit or mitre.com using beautifulsoup (python lib). But we will have a problem in case where they decide to change their HTML template.

Solution 2 :  @schroede

Parse CSV archive of db-exploit using csv python lib. Here a simple [script](https://github.com/mattoufoutu/exploitdb/blob/master/exploitdb.py) to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at http://www.exploit-db.com and http://www.cvedetails.com/. They don't have any REST service, but they do offer free searching.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but [exploit-db](http://exploit-db.com) and [cvedetails](http://cvedetails.com) offer results only in HTML form.

Comment: And writing a simple parser is too hard?

Comment: exploit-db's archive in csv form would also have what you need.